# Adobe Acrobat Reader - Cursor does not go away

Tags: adobe

I have a question about adobe acrobat reader.

So, when I open any PDF file, I used to click the right or left arrow to jump between pages.

Recently though I am unable to do this because, once the PDF file is opened, a "Cursor" is already there, and so when I click the right or left arrows, the Cursor moves between letters.

I do not know how to get red of this Cursor. It just there.

Is there a way to get rid of it??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to 'Edit' -> 'Preferences' -> 'Accessibility' -> Under 'Other Accessibility Options', there is a checkbox 'Always display the keyboard selection cursor'. Un-check this and you are good to go.

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you so so much. 
This has been driving me crazy for months now!!
Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to remove the cursor again once it is there (e.g., because I misclicked)? Because then I am forced to restart the reader if I want to use LEFT and RIGHT as before to skip pages. :(